# How to create a trigger on table A that inserts/updates entity in table B?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables `TableAAA`, `TableBBB`, `TableCCC` and `TableCollected`. The `AAA/BBB/CCC` tables have a `DateTime` column:

```
table_aaa: DateTime modified
table_bbb: DateTime modified
table_ccc: DateTime modified
```

I'd like to have a 1-1 trigger on each table that runs after inserting/updating. It should save the biggest `DateTime` from given table into the `TableCollected` table. So if `TableAAA` table contains 3 rows with dates `1980-01-01`, `1990-01-01` and `2010-01-01` then in `TableCollected` I'd have a row that contains the name of the table (or some identifier, it's okay if I have to set it) and the biggest date `table_collected: name (table_aaa), modified (2010-01-01)`.

If `TableBBB` has rows with `1999-01-01`, `2012-04-01`, `TableCollected` should have 2 rows:

```
name        datetime
table_aaa  2010-01-01
table_bbb  2012-04-01
```

So `TableCollected` would hold the biggest `DateTime` of other tables. It should contain each table's `DateTime` value just once. The `name` is unique and if it inserted once, it should update every time a new row is inserted in table `AAA/BBB/CCC` and `modified` value is bigger than the old value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 3 triggers for every table, one for insert, one for update and one for delete (if the most recently modified record is deleted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_aaa_insert AFTER INSERT ON table_aaa 
BEGIN
  INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TableCollected (name, modified) 
  SELECT 'table_aaa', max(modified) FROM table_aaa;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER table_aaa_update AFTER UPDATE ON table_aaa 
BEGIN
  INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TableCollected (name, modified) 
  SELECT 'table_aaa', max(modified) FROM table_aaa;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER table_aaa_delete AFTER DELETE ON table_aaa 
BEGIN
  INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TableCollected (name, modified) 
  SELECT 'table_aaa', max(modified) FROM table_aaa;
END;
```

Note that `name` must be a primary key or a unique field of `TableCollected` to take advantage of `INSERT OR REPLACE`

However, depending on the rate of insert/update/delete operations on those tables, it could be more efficient to replace your TableCollected table with a view which dynamically returns the desired values:

```
CREATE VIEW TableCollected (name, modified) as
  SELECT 'table_aaa', max(modified) from table_aaa
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'table_bbb', max(modified) from table_bbb
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'table_ccc', max(modified) from table_ccc;
```

In both solutions, an index on `modified` field in tables aaa, bbb, and ccc would be beneficial to performance.

EDIT:
On second thought, a more efficient way which doesn't require to calculate max(modified) every time a record is inserted or updated is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_aaa_insert AFTER INSERT ON table_aaa 
BEGIN
  UPDATE TableCollected SET modified=NEW.modified WHERE name='table_aaa' AND modified<NEW.modified;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER table_aaa_update AFTER UPDATE ON table_aaa 
BEGIN
  UPDATE TableCollected SET modified=NEW.modified WHERE name='table_aaa' AND modified<NEW.modified;
END;
```

DELETE trigger doesn't change because in that case you need to search for max(modified) anyway.

Note that this solution requires to pre-populate TableCollected with a row for each table. Also note that in the trigger `modified` refers to the TableCollected field, and `NEW.modified` refers to the table_aaa field which was just inserted or updated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is Yes. Here is an example from the official docs:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_customer_address UPDATE OF address ON customers 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE orders SET address = new.address WHERE customer_name = old.name;
  END;
```